# PHP different result of getttype() on apache and IIS

Tags: php, laravel, apache, iis

Production server is:

- Windows 10 pro
- IIS 10.0.17134.1
- PHP version 7.1.17

My local machine:

- macOS, Mojave 10.14
- Apache/2.4.37 (Unix)
- PHP version 7.2.12

On both machines I'm using same laravel 5.4 application that uses the same source(database) on the same Microsoft SQL server using sqlsrv PDO installed following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017).

In **reports** table, **is_active** filed is type of tinyint.

On windows machine:

```
  $report = App\Report::find(1);

  return gettype($report->is_active); //returns string
```

On macOS machine:

```
  $report = App\Report::find(1);

  return gettype($report->is_active); //returns integer
```

So when I'm developing on my localhost and push changes to production it fails on basic comparison:

```
 if($report->is_active === 1){
       // works on localhost, but not on production
 }
```

Comment: Just drop the 3rd equal sign on your comparison. Or cast the value to an int on the return. `if($report->is_active == 1){`

Comment: Have a look at [`PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/constants-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) or cast each string yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Salaman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) mention in the comment, look at [`PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/constants-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

On the production server, I added `options` array in **database.php** file.

```
  'sqlsrv' => [
        // defaults ...
        'options' => [
            PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE => true
        ]
    ],
```

That solved my problem, now on both machines `gettype($report->is_active)` return `integer`.